# JS problems with adding li

Tags: javascript, html-lists

I have a problem with adding li. When I add new li text be in first li and should be in the next. https://jsfiddle.net/zaxmy1nw/1/ 
Probably problem is here.

```
function NewLI(){
    AddLi;
    userp.appendChild(userName);
    LiP.appendChild(LiText);

    var UladdLi = document.getElementById("chat").appendChild(AddLi);
    var AddP = document.getElementById("lispan").appendChild(LiP);
    var UseraddLi = document.getElementById("lispan").appendChild(userp);
}
```

Comment: What output do you expect? Do you want the newly added `li` to have the text selected in the `select` dropdown?

Comment: What does `AddLi;` do? It looks like you're creating a global variable with no value...

Answer (score 0):

You select by Id, but all `li` elements have the same id (`lispan`) so selecting by id will always return the first one.

What you can do is :

```
function NewLI(){
    AddLi;
    userp.appendChild(userName);
    LiP.appendChild(LiText);
    AddLi.appendChild(LiP)
    AddLi.appendChild(userp)
    var UladdLi = document.getElementById("chat").appendChild(AddLi);

}
```

see : https://jsfiddle.net/zaxmy1nw/2/

Comment: This is it! Thank you :D

Comment: I don't know how useful this will be to you know that you've got the answer you were looking for but here's something that I quickly thew together in JSBin that might be of use to you: https://jsfiddle.net/ubLx7u80/2/